# How do i get all keys in Mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

I saw few solutions but those are not exact my solution. I have a DB with name results and collection name is marks like below:

```
db.marks.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f57522627af4bfdcf79764"), "name" : "John", "scroe1" : 23, "score2" : 21, "score5" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f5761a627af4bfdcf79765"), "name" : "Mike", "scroe2" : 22, "score3" : 20, "score4" : 22 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559d0bc521cb2e056507c3e3"), "name" : "Bush", "score2" : 30 }
```

I tried with

```
var doc=db.marks.findOne(); for (var key in doc) print(key);
```

and i got

```
_id
name
score1
score2
score5
```

But i Want all keys in collection like below:

```
_id, name, score1, score2, score3, score4, score5
```

name
scroe1
score2
score3here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

findOne will only return the first found document.  Since the first document you list does not have the score3 and score4 keys, it will not display them.  If you want to show all root-level keys across all documents, you would need to iterate through all the documents in the db.

```
var keys = [];
db.marks.find().forEach(function(doc){
    for (var key in doc){ 
        if(keys.indexOf(key) < 0){
           keys.push(key);
        }
    }
});

print(keys);
```

Comment: Can I get nested keys' list using such approach?

Comment: @AarohiKulkarni You could, but you would need to check the type of the value of doc[key], and if it is an object, you can iterate over it with another nested for...in loop.  If it is an array, then you would need to loop over the array, checking the value of each array, and if its an object, then loop over that object's keys.

Comment: @MatthewAntolovich is it possible without using for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "my_collection",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})
```

Then run distinct on the resulting collection so as to find all the keys:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["foo", "bar", "baz", "_id", ...]
```

Answer (score -3):

Mongodb `find()` command has two arguments first one is query and second is projections.

Something like `db.collection.find(query,projection)`.

if the document is `db.myCol.find();`, then it returns:

```
{
  {
    _id:1
    name: ''hello',
    age: 23
  }, {
    _id:2
    name: ''bollo',
    age: 27
  }
}
```

And `db.myCol.find({},{_id:1});` returns:

```
1
2
```

Comment: This will only return the `_id`s of the documents, not all of the keys in the document.